# Does implementing the following functionality violate Google Play policies?

Tags: android, google-play, policies

An app called [Bass Booster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desaxedstudios.bassbooster&hl=en_US) has the functionality of displaying a list of installed applications that are possibly incompatible with it.

I plan to implement in my app a similar function, which shows the list of apps that may be incompatible and the following message: "The following apps may present conflicts with XBooster. Please check them and take the necessary actions to avoid conflicts between your sound apps. "

This function would be very useful to identify installed apps that can interfere with each other and hinder the operation of all installed equalizers (including preinstalled).

But in the following link of developer policies:

https://play.google.com/intl/en/about/privacy-security-deception/deceptive-behavior/#!?zippy_activeEl=deceptive-settings#deceptive-settings

It can be read that they do not allow the following:

> "Apps that encourage or incentivize users into removing or disabling
>   third-party apps or modifying device settings or features unless it is
>   part of a verifiable security service."

Does implementing the function that would show a list of apps that could be incompatible, somehow incentivize users to take the action of removing or uninstalling them?

I would like to know the opinion of the other developers about it.

I don't know how to contact the Google Play support team to ask about my question and avoid implementing a function that could cause me problems.

If this is not the right place to post this question, help me know where I should post it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding the Google Play policies should be posted on the respective forums, not StackOverflow.

Comment: @Edric I said I don't know how to contact the Google Play team. Could you tell us which are the "respective forums"?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know the opinion of the other developers about it.

SO is a *question* and *answer* site - not an opinion forum. Questions like "will this violate Google Play policies" are best directed to a lawyer.

> I don't know how to contact the Google Play support team to ask about my question and avoid implementing a function that could cause me problems.

Try the Android Developer Console help. Click the "?" icon in the top right, then down to "Contact Us / Need more help".

[image: Android Developer Console Hlep]

However, it's highly unlikely you'll get any good / direct answer. Google Play "support" is notoriously vague about what constitutes violations of the policy (presumably so people don't game the system / sue them).

> If this is not the right place to post this question, help me know where I should post it.

Maybe try Twitter, Reddit, or some such platform where you can query the masses for their hot takes on a question.

Hope that helps!